# Summary of MySQL detail records matching by IP address ranges

Tags: mysql

So, I have to draw upon all the powers of the greatest mySQL minds that SO has to offer.  I have to summarize detail records based on the IP address in each record.  Here's the scenario:

In short, we have consortiums that want to know: "***Which schools within my consortium watched which videos how many times***"?  In SQL terms, it amounts to COUNTing the detail records, grouped by which IP range it might fall into.

1. We have several university Consortiums - each with a handful of different schools that are members.
2. Each school within a consortium uses various IP ranges to access the videos that we serve to these schools.
3. The IP Ranges are specified with wild cards, so each school specifies something like '100.200.35.x, 100.201.x.x, 100.202.39.50, etc.', with the average number of ranges per school being 10 or 15.
4. The raw text log files to summarize are already in a database (one row for each log entry), and has the actual IP address that accessed the video file.
5. There are 100's of millions of detail records, so I fully expect this to be a long slow process that runs for a considerable period.
6. PHP scripts exist that can "explode" the wildcards into the individual IPs that are represented, but I fear this will be the final answer and could take weeks to run.

(*For simplicity sake, I'm only going to refer to the video filename that was accessed and COUNT the log entries for it, but in fact all the details such as start/stop/duration,etc. are there and will ultimately be part of this solution*.)

With Consortium records something like this: (*All table designs except log details open to suggestion*):

```
| id|consortium   |
| 10|Ivy League   |
| 20|California   |
```

And School/IP records something like this:

```
|  id|school     |consortium_id|
| 101|Harvard    |10           |
| 102|Yale       |10           |
| 103|UCLA       |20           |
| 104|Berkeley   |20           |

| id|school_id|ip_range         |
|  1| 101     |100.200.x.x      |
|  2| 101     |100.201.65.x     |
|  3| 101     |100.202.39.50    |
|  4| 101     |100.202.39.51    |
|  5| 101     |100.200.x.x      |
|  6| 101     |100.201.65.x     |
|  7| 101     |100.202.39.50    |
```

And detail records something like this:

```
|session     |ip_address     |filename          |
|560554790925|100.202.390.500|history101.mp4    |
|406417611526|43.22.90.5     |newsreel.mp4      |
|650423700223|100.202.39.50  |history101.mp4    |
|650423700223|100.202.50.12  |science101.mp4    |
|513057324209|100.202.39.56  |history101.mp4    |
```

I like to think I'm pretty handy with mySQL, but this one is stretching it, and am hoping that there's a spectacular function or set of steps that someone might offer.

Comment: Having dealt with this kind of thing in University library consortial code for some years, my first recommendation is to change to storage type of your ranges away from the .x to a start and end int representation using `INET_ATON()` or PHP's `ip2long()`.  Doing so will require some scripting, but will be well worth the effort later on.

Comment: @Gregp I don't get the question but to store ips into mysql the best way is with the functions INET_ATON() and INET_NTOA() take a look here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html

Comment: Ah..the int idea is great.  It's a legacy database - 10yrs worth of video detail (down to the start/stop/pause/play level), so you can imagine how many records there are.

Comment: Oh lordy, if its that precise, and based from a university, I can only imagine how many non allowed videos might be in that list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your existing data structure, you could do string matching as follows (but it's not very efficient):

```
SELECT   schools.school, detail.filename, COUNT(*)
FROM     schools
    JOIN ipranges ON schools.id = ipranges.school_id
    JOIN detail   ON detail.ip_address LIKE REPLACE(ipranges.ip_range, 'x', '%')
WHERE    schools.consortium_id = ?
GROUP BY schools.school, detail.filename
```

A better way would be to store your IP ranges as network address and prefix length:

```
ALTER TABLE ipranges
  ADD COLUMN network INT UNSIGNED,
  ADD COLUMN prefix  TINYINT;
UPDATE ipranges SET
  network = INET_ATON(REPLACE(ip_range, 'x', 0)),
  prefix  = 32 - 8*(CHAR_LENGTH(ip_range) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(ip_range,'x',''));
ALTER TABLE ipranges
  DROP COLUMN ip_range;

ALTER TABLE detail
  ADD COLUMN ip_address_new INT UNSIGNED;
UPDATE detail SET
  ip_address_new = INET_ATON(ip_address);
ALTER TABLE detail
  DROP COLUMN ip_address,
  CHANGE ip_address_new ip_address INT UNSIGNED;
```

Then it would merely be a case of performing some bit comparisons:

```
SELECT   schools.school, detail.filename, COUNT(*)
FROM     schools
    JOIN ipranges ON schools.id = ipranges.school_id
    JOIN detail   ON detail.ip_address & ~((1 << 32 - ipranges.prefix) - 1)
                   = ipranges.network
WHERE    schools.consortium_id = ?
GROUP BY schools.school, detail.filename
```

Comment: if storing the Mask as INET_ATON('255.255.0.0'), he could do some quick bitwise operations to determine if the IP is in range or not.

Comment: It's sound like I'll have to "explode" the IP ranges to the individual address, and work with the numeric equivalent (which makes sense).  I don't understand what "prefix" is, or it's purpose.

Comment: @GregP: Prefix is the number of bits of the IP address that represent the network (with the remainder representing hosts on that network).  Since each octet (between the dots) is 8-bits, a prefix of 24 indicates that the first three octets are the network address, and the remaining octet is the host address.  And you don't *have to* do it that way (although it is better): you could use the string comparison version given in my first example without changing any of your existing data.

Comment: Ah..."network stuff"...no wonder, lol - network tech stuff burns my eyes, lol. but that's *very* handy information to have in this endeavour.

Comment: @GregP: See my revised answer above for how to put it all together.

Comment: @eggyal- I've seen your answers before, so have due respect for your given solution.  I'm going to tinker with it for a day to wrap my mind around it, then officially accept an answer.

Comment: @GregP: No problem... you might want to read up on [CIDR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing)?  Good luck!

Comment: @GregP: I searched around a bit... [this tutorial](http://software77.net/cidr-101.html) looks relatively accessible.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT D.filename, S.school, COUNT(D.*)
FROM detail_records AS D
     INNER JOIN ip_map AS I ON D.ip_address LIKE CONCAT(SUBSTRING(I.ip_range, 1, LOCATE('x', I.ip_range)-1), '%')
     INNER JOIN school AS S ON S.id = I.school_id
     INNER JOIN consortium AS C ON C.id = S.consortium_id
WHERE S.consortium_id = <consortium identifier>
GROUP BY D.filename, S.school
```