# Limit specific page access based off of physical location

Tags: php, html, ip

For a project at my school, I would like to allow members to 'sign-in' at the end of meetings to show their attendance. Obviously, there will be people who arn't at the meetings and will try to cheat the system.

The way I was going to go about this was

- Restrict a form from being submitted (through php) if their IP is not within the range of the school's network
- Prevent one device from submitting twice (add a week-long cookie)

I am not sure if my IP method is the best way to go about this, or if I'm entirely going about it wrong. So before I get too far into research; is this the best way to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To restrict submissions to a certain IP range, you may want to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121817/how-to-check-an-ip-address-is-within-a-range-of-two-ips-in-php). However, this only works if the device used is in your school's network, and you would have to add some time constraint (so claiming participation the day after does not work).

As for cookies, those can be deleted by the user. For you, it may actually suffice to remember the logins used, and if they have been submitted for the week in question.

All in all, you may be easier off printing a list that participants have to sign...