# How to select ip address in between the ip range from database using query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have `ip_table` as below. Suppose my `IP address is 1.22.13.15`. But in my table this exact IP address is not available, This IP address is in the range between `0/24`. How can I get the `geoname_id` for this IP address? Can someone assist me? Or there is any other way?

```
+---------------+------------+
| ip_adr        | geoname_id |
+---------------+------------+
| 1.22.13.0/24  |    1279233 |
| 1.22.130.0/23 |    1273294 |
| 1.22.132.0/23 |    1267995 |
| 1.22.134.0/23 |    1253405 |
| 1.22.136.0/21 |    1269750 |
+---------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RegEx` in `SQL` to identify the format of IP and check if the selected IP is in the range you give.

**Example:**

```
SELECT *
FROM ips
WHERE (ip_addr REGEXP '^[0-9]{1}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2,3}\.0\/(24)')
```

Comment: I want to check IP address for multiple users.

Comment: you select first the users table left join the ip table ?

Comment: the users table contains an field with ip range ?

Comment: Don't have user table. Just have above table.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no MySQL function that can deal with the range syntax for IP adresses directly.
But MySQL has a function to convert IP adresses in a bigint number: INET_ATON()

one possible solution would be to extend the table structure in such a way that you can use simple queries:

```
|ip_adr_range_start  |ip_adr_range_end | geoname_id|
|[bigint]            |[bigint]         | [int?]
```

the first row would be inserted like this:

```
INSERT INTO your_table VALUES (INET_ATON('1.22.13.0'), INET_ATON('1.22.13.255'), 1279233);
```

a query could be:

```
SELECT * from your_table 
WHERE ip_adr_range_start < INET_ATON('1.22.13.15') 
AND ip_adr_range_end > INET_ATON('1.22.13.15')
```

ideas taken from here:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36451/convert-the-ip-address-range-to-two-bigint-for-faster-lookup

Answer (score 1):

try Substring_index

`select  left('1.22.13.0/24',length('1.22.13.0/24')-
  length(substring_index('1.22.13.0/24','.',-1))) 
  part1,substring_index(substring_index('1.22.13.0/24','.',-1),'/',1) as 
  range_start,substring_index('1.22.13.0/24','/',-1) range_end`

the output will be

`part1   | range_start| range_end`

`1.22.13.| 0          | 24`

then you can compare your value accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I guess this table mean the ip in range between 1.22.13.0-1.22.13.255 will match with 1279233 geonameid.
You need to define IP range by subnet provided.
So, to get a geonameid with specific ip, just ask it what are its IP and subnet?
How to compare the specific ip address with ip range and compare with geonameid? More info at [How to check an IP address is within a range of two IPs in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121817/how-to-check-an-ip-address-is-within-a-range-of-two-ips-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

I got the output using the following query.

I split my `IP` address into two parts. Like `1.22.13` and `15` passed these in `where` condition.

```
SELECT ip_adr, geoname_id
FROM ip_table 
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ip_adr, '/', 1 ), '.', 3) = 
'1.22.13' AND
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ip_adr, '/', 1 ), '.', -1) <= '15';
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
with ipaddressTBL as(
    select *,  INET_ATON(ip) as ipaddress from `routers` 
) select * from ipaddressTBL 
where ipaddress BETWEEN INET_ATON('32.248.135.197') AND INET_ATON('165.9.105.127')
```

Comment: Please add a description note. How this answer helps op?